# How do i set the value of a based on a dropdown in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm a .Net developer but i'm just geting start at ASP .NET MVC and i have a question
(I'm brazilian, so i'm gona try to explain)

I have a Model called "Consulta". One of the property of Consulta is "Ativo".
In my DataBase this field can only be 1 or 0, but in my view, i have a EnumDropDownListFor that shows the options "Sim" or "Não" (Sim = 1; Não = 0).
To populate my EnumDropDownListFor i created an Enum:

```
public enum Ativo
{
    [Display(Name = "Não")]
    Nao = 0,                        
    Sim = 1            
}
```

and in Consulta i created a property called "AtivoList" so i can use my enum:

```
[NotMapped]
private SpeEnum.Ativo ativoList;
[NotMapped]
public SpeEnum.Ativo AtivoList
{
    get
    {
        if (Ativo == 0)
            return SpeEnum.Ativo.Nao;
        else
            return SpeEnum.Ativo.Sim;

    }
    set { ativoList = value; }
}
```

First i had to set the value "Sim" as default on my dropdown, so i did it in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Consulta consulta = new Consulta();
    consulta.Ativo = 1;

    return View(consulta);
}
```

Now i have my problem: how can i set the value of the property "Ativo" based on my dorpdown? I can't do this on my model because it will aways get the value 1.

Comment: add your view source in question as well.

Comment: I think you should resarch "Form Post" a bit to understand MVC a bit better.

Comment: What @Greg said. In addition, in your HttpPost Ativo will be whatever the user sets it to in the Create (HttpGet) View, (which is were you set it to 1 as a default).